# Trying to remember a Movie 1950'/1960's Fantasy Adventure with a Flying Machine and Cloud City

Tags: story-identification, movie

I have not watched this film in at least over a decade and I can only remember small details such as

- The Film is in Colour
- Live-Action and most likely filmed on stage

**Plot Points**

- The party of scientists/adventurers scale a treacherous mountain while fighting off giant condor type birds (this would be midway in the film)
- They acquire somehow a flying machine that they use to discover a city in the clouds

Comment: A Sinbad movie with the giant birds being Rocs?

Comment: Thanks, Moriarty, but the film is not a Sinbad story

Comment: Do you remember anything about the special effects? Any stop-motion? models?

Comment: I FOUND THE MOVIE! I was wrong about the year it turns out it's from 1974. I guess when I was watching this as a kid it looked bad so I assumed it was older than it was.

The Island at the Top of the World

Comment: Theatrical Release: December 20, 1974 / Running Time: 94 Minutes / Rating: G

Director: Robert Stevenson / Writers: John Whedon (screenplay), Ian Cameron (novel)

Cast: David Hartman (Prof. John Ivarsson), Donald Sinden (Sir Anthony Ross), Jacques Marin (Captain Brieux), Mako (Oomiak), David Gwillim (Donald Ross), Agneta Eckemyr (Freyja), Gunnar Öhlund (The Godi), Lasse Kolstad (Erik), Erik Silju (Torvald), Rolf Søder (The Lawspeaker)

Comment: Nice that you found it, Darryl! Please post it as an answer in the answer field below :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Answering on behalf of OP (DarrylMcCartney) who self-answered in comments on original question.*

The film in question is **The Island at the Top of the World**.

[image]

From the movie's [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Island_at_the_Top_of_the_World) article:

> The Island at the Top of the World is a **1974 American live-action lost
> world fantasy adventure film** directed by Robert Stevenson and produced
> by Winston Hibler. It was released by Walt Disney Productions,
> distributed by Buena Vista Distribution and starring Donald Sinden and
> David Hartman.
>
> In London in the year 1907, a British aristocrat, industrialist and
> millionaire named Sir Anthony Ross (Donald Sinden) hastily arranges an
> **expedition to the Arctic** to search for his lost son Donald. Donald has
> become lost on a whaling expedition to find the fabled island where
> whales go to die.
>
> Sir Anthony employs the talents of a Scandinavian-American
> archaeologist Professor John Ivarsson (David Hartman) and Captain
> Brieux (Jacques Marin), a French inventor/aeronaut who pilots the
> expedition in a French **dirigible named the Hyperion**, which Captain
> Brieux invented. Upon reaching the Arctic, they meet Oomiak (Mako
> Iwamatsu), a comically cowardly/brave Eskimo friend of Donald's, and
> trick him into helping them join in the search.

Comment: Thank you for catching that. :-D Answers are searchable (and have more details). Comments are not.